# Why is there no default java implementation of Delayed for DelayQueue?

Tags: java, events, delay, runnable, future

I'd like a [`DelayQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) of scheduled `Runnable`s, where each `Runnable`s should only be run after a certain point in time, specified beforehand. Hence a thread can just keep removing runnables from this queue and process a schedule of events. Why is there no good default implementation of [`Delayed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Delayed.html), that is also `Runnable`, for this?

The only subinterface of `Delayed` that seems reasonable is [`RunnableScheduledFuture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RunnableScheduledFuture.html), which has a whole bunch of random things that need to be implemented. There has to be an easier way to do this, right?

Comment: is it not easy to impl one yourself?

Comment: you may simply use a ScheduledExecutorService

Comment: I always search for existing implementations before rolling my own. Yes, I think `ScheduledExecutorService` was what I was looking for :) Why don't you convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DelayQueue is more of an infrastructure class that's not used directly by application.

You are probably better off using a ScheduledExecutorService (which internally uses a variant of DelayQueue)

Comment: Great, no idea how I overlooked that! :)