# Confused by DelayQueue

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduled-tasks, java.util.concurrent

I've found `DelayQueue`, which is exactly what I need. In general, I agree that [a `ScheduledExecutorService` is better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15102538/581205), but I already have an executor and I want full control of the timing.

So I have to implement the `Delayed` interface. This forced me to add `clock` (an instance of my tiny wrapper around `java.time.Clock`), so I get the current time:

```
private final Instant expires;
private final Clock clock; // UGLY!!!

public long getDelay(TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    return timeUnit.convert(
            Duration.between(expires, clock.now()).toNanos(),
            TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
}
```

Now I need to implement `Comparable<Delayed>`, i.e., to compare instances of my class to *any* instance of `Delayed`. I guess that

```
public int compareTo(Delayed that) {
   return instant.compareTo(((MyClass) that).instant);
}
```

would lead to a `ClassCastException` somewhere. The other possibility is using

```
public int compareTo(Delayed that) {
    return Long.compare(
          this.getDelay(TimeUnit.NANOSECOND),
          that.getDelay(TimeUnit.NANOSECOND));
}
```

But such a method could have been implemented in the interface (there's nothing specific to my class there) or simply omitted as the queue could use a corresponding `Comparator`.

Moreover, as `getDelay` depends on the current time, it's not possible to implement the method really correctly as some time passes between the invocations. For example, `myInstance.compareTo(myInstance)` would return non-zero because of this. This case can be easily countered by testing `this==that` first, however I can't see any general solution (apart from some ugly `ThreadLocal` hack).

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you need to implement `Comparable<Delayed>`? I might be missing it, but I don't see that `DelayQueue` requires it.

Comment: @daniu `Delayed` extends `Comparable<Delayed>`.

Comment: Huh, so I did miss it. Well looking at JDK code of implementors of the interface, subtracting the `getDelay`-results is what it boils down to...

Comment: @daniu Agreed, I should've looked at it first. However, it's not really correct, is it?

Comment: @maaartinus It's not. It probably doesn't really matter in practice because the comparison operation only happens upon insertion into the queue (to keep it sorted), so a few milliseconds difference is not an issue.

Comment: @daniu I'm not sure. The underlying data structure is a `PriorityQueue`. By blowing up the comparison, you lose the heap property. I guess, any inconsistency may affect also unrelated entries. However, I believe that small variations in `getDelay` would cause only small errors, i.e., returning entries in wrong order, but only if they're close to each other. Still this would need some analysis rather than guesswork.